# How to prevent outgoing call in android with a service?

Tags: android, android-service, call, system-calls, background-service

I wanna make a service that when it is active and the user presses the call button, whether in the OS phone app or in the contacts, it prevents outgoing call. I mean instead of running android calling service, i want my service to be run.
Is there any way to do so?
I am really beginner in android programming and i don't really know a lot about android services. 
I'll appreciate you to help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: look at this http://www.emoticode.net/android-sdk/block-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-programmatically.html, I've not tried it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use BroadcastReceiver for this.

in manifest you have to write

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>    

<receiver android:name=".OutGoingCallListener">
       <intent-filter android:priority="0">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
       </intent-filter>

   </receiver>
```

And in class which extends from BroadcastReceiver you have to write

```
public class OutGoingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER).toString();

       //if u want to block particular call then check number or else block all call in thid code

        setResultData(null);//Canceling call operation 
        Toast.makeText(context, "This call is not Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


} }
```

Comment: it shows the message but it doesn't end call! is there any way to do so? I think setResultData(null) doesn't work!